# String concatenation with arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing, xbee

I have a very short example program running on an Arduino Fio device. This program is sending serial data. A connected Xbee router device is receiving this data and sending it to a Xbee coordinator device connected to my notebook. The program also reading data from the serial port. I can send a `1` or a `0` to switch the LED of the Fio device on or off.

Switching the LED on or off by sending a `1` or a `0` from a terminal on my notebook is working well.

But when I try to read the data which the Fio device is sending, I get this:

```
his direction works 
is direction works 
s direction works 
 direction works 
direction works 
irection works 
rection works 
ection works 
ction works
```

... and so on.

But I'm expecting a string (`"This direction works " + counter++;`) as you can see in the following code example.

Here is the short Arduino sketch:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data
 int counter = 0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(57600);
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);

    // blink twice at startup
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);

    digitalWrite(13, HIGH); // first blink
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH); // second blink
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void loop()
{   
    // send data only when you receive data:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) 
    {
        // read the incoming byte:
        incomingByte = Serial.read();

        if(incomingByte == '0')
        {
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        }
        else if(incomingByte == '1')
        {
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        }

        // say what you got:
        Serial.print("Fio received: ");
        Serial.write(incomingByte);  // Arduino 1.0 compatibility
        Serial.write(10);    // send a line feed/new line, ascii 10
    }
    else
    {
        String sendData = "This direction works " + counter++;
        Serial.println(sendData);       
        delay(1500);
    }   
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why do I don't get:

```
This direction works 0
This direction works 1
This direction works 2
This direction works 3
```

... and so on?

Comment: This is not [tag:c], althought most arduino programmers think it is apparently.

Comment: @iharob Ok, I changed the tag to "processing" programming language.

Comment: Change Serial.write(incomingByte), to Serial.print(incomingByte). Does it works? write expects single character.

Comment: @Elric Why should that work? There is no problem with receiving data (inside the if (Serial.available() > 0) clause). There is a problem with the sending data inside the else-clause.

Comment: My mistake. In the else clause, separate the string from the variable, use two separate Serial println and Serial print. The way you want to do would need a sprintf in between and would consume more resources.

Comment: Is the `+` operator overloaded for `const char *`? - very unlikely. ""This direction works " + counter++" really does not do what you think. Use correct concatenation.

Comment: @Elric It is working! Thanks. But why do I have to do this that way? I thought I can use the '+' operator (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator)?

Comment: A _string literal_ does not have `string` type!

Comment: @Olaf In other programming languages concatenation is working this way.

Comment: And in Python you use `for i in "Hello": ...` to get the characters in a string one by one. What does that prove? **different** languages have **different** features. So what?

Comment: @Olaf I just wanted to say, usually this way for concatenation worked for me. That's why I thought it is working with arduino to. And I still don't understand why firstly I have to initialize the String variable to concatenate two strings!?

Comment: @CPA, Arduino is really similar to C, so I recommend learning C. I believe the most important difference is that while you can practice C in your computer that has almost unlimited resources, your Arduino can be maxed pretty fast, requiring some caution in the development. Also you usually can find tutorials, materials, and courses on C easier than the same material on Arduino and usually they are more clear when explaining why and how things works.

Comment: @Elric: Processing is based on C++, not C. So OP should learn C++. Or refrain from using Processing and directly use C. Takes more effort, but teaches more about details.

Comment: @Elric Yeah I know, I learned c years ago. For big projects I will use C, but for these small prototyping projects it is faster to use Arduino.

Comment: @CPA: Do you expect e.g. a German word to have the same meaning in English, even if it has the same spelling? For instance look up the words "norm" and "standard" (perfectly false friends) in German and English (Rhetorical question, just review your expectations in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Elric and @Olaf mentioned in the comments, it is not possible to do that like in my posted code.

After reading the documentation again I found an "explanation":

> Caution: You should be careful about concatenating multiple variable
>   types on the same line, as you may get unexpected results. For
>   example:
>
> int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);    String stringOne = "Sensor
>   value: ";   String stringThree = stringOne + sensorValue;
>   Serial.println(stringThree);
>
> results in "Sensor Value: 402" or whatever the analogRead() result is,
>   but
>
> int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);    String stringThree = "Sensor
>   value: " + sensorValue;   Serial.println(stringThree);
>
> gives unpredictable results because stringThree never got an initial
>   value before you started concatenating different data types.

Firstly you have to initialize the String variable to assign two concatenated strings to it.